# "Turn the hose on someone"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I've been translating TV series called This is Us and I didn't understand this part.

Randall is poor father William's rich child. William is staying with them and in this episode, Randall's rich neighbors are reporting William for being suspicious(like, poor guy walking in rich neighborhood) Then Randall comes, apologizes for him. After this, dialogues are like that,

> R: Would you have been happier if I made a big scene?
>   You know, got up in Tony's face, had the cops roll up and **turn the
>   hoses on us?**
>
> W: You ever had a **hose turned on you?**
>
> R: Can't say that I have, I'm very sorry.
>
> W: Don't be. It hurts.

I really didn't understand this "turn hose on someone" part. I searched about this but can someone help me?

Comment: This phrase was used in a 1954 song called “Call a Doctor” by The Crows. “Call the doctor, fire department, yes, she turned the hose on me” https://youtu.be/upMlnKcEVDs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn the hose on someone in reference to the police is a reference to police using fire hoses to disperse a crowd.

The police use fire hoses to aim water at crowds to break them up. One sees this on television sometimes.

Here is an example of it  on UTube: [hosing the crowd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We1CWIvDsOA)

Answer (score 2):

The preposition **on** here indicates having the object of the preposition as a target. So hoses turned on someone means that person is the target of the hoses.

Similarly you can say:

> She bailed **on** me.
>
> Don't die **on** me!

A hose is a flexible tube usually used as water ducts. Here the reference is to [fire hose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_hose). As a verb, "hose" means to drench someone with water from a hose.